# How to hide windows or open it behind main aplication

Tags: wpf

I need to open new window behind main screen. This code doesn't work for me.
Lets assume I have 2 classes

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
 <Grid>
    <Button Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
</Grid>
 private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Test t=new Test();
        t.Show();
    }
```

**Test** class that I need to open behind Main window

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Test" Height="350" Width="525" ShowInTaskbar="False" Visibility="Hidden"   >
<Grid>
    <TextBox/>
</Grid>
```

I try to use **ShowInTaskbar="False" Visibility="Hidden"** but it still doesn't work. The problem I can see "Test" windows 1 sec and after it will be unviable(because Visibility="Hidden") .I need to open this windows many times, it will blinks many times. The better solution to open it behind application.
Is anyone knows how to do?

Comment: this Test window will close on your command or what? because i don't get the sense of the Visibility = Hidden. Also if it doesn't need to mantain the state (since you are doing Test = new Test() ) why you are just not using a popup control?

Comment: This is only demo. I need to open window behind main window.In the test window I will add user control and do what I need and after will close it manualy. The project is big I don't want to put All the MVVM modules.

Comment: Ok, so i repeat, is there any particular reason on why you are not using a Popup control? You can define a custom view to place inside it and show him whenever you want easily without messing with other window

Comment: I need to export data to pdf. So all the Views(user controls) will be inside of the test window. After I will open the new test window I will take snapshot of the screen and export data to pdf.That is the reason why I need new window behind application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the `Topmost` property of the `MainWindow` to `true`:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Test t = new Test();
    t.Show();

    Topmost = true;
}
```

This should cause the `Test` window to be displayed "behind" the main window.

Answer (score 0):

The final solution for me

```
if (Application.Current.MainWindow != null)
                {
                    Application.Current.MainWindow.Topmost=true;
                }
```